# Poskim who hold chalita is necessary?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat

Are there any famous rishonim or achronim (outside of Yemen & besides the Rambam) who hold doing chalita to meat is necessary?

Comment: the Rambam in הלכות מאכלות אסורות פרק ו

Comment: Even the Rambam didn't hold of it if you were roasting it or eating it raw. (And, no, the Rambam didn't live in Yemen.)

Comment: This question really needs some editing. First, the term requires definition. It is jargon without it. Second, the Yemenite requirement comes from the Rambam, so the question doesn't hold on its own. Third, famous is way too vague. Almost opinion based. Especially when discussing Achronim. Fourth a link which gives some background would be *really* helpful. Here is one: http://www.chayas.com/kosherissues.htm

Comment: @doubleaa , Igros Teiman,I believe he visited there before or lived there shortly don't remember,are you sure

Comment: @sam Well, ya, he wrote them a letter. I don't know of any evidence that he visited there

Comment: Well he know the Rabbi he was speaking too

Comment: @DoubleAA If the Rambam didn't hold of it if you were "roasting it" so then when is it required? How else do you prepare meat if not be either putting it into a pot of water and "cooking it" (which would essentially be chalita) or putting on a grill or in the oven (i.e. roasting where the Rambam doesn't require chalita as you say.

Comment: @yeho you can cook by putting it in cold water and bringing to a boil. Also dry roasting in a pan without drainage is problematic too.

Comment: I found [this article](https://forthodoxy.files.wordpress.com/2017/08/is-halitah-necessary-2.pdf) that should help. (I don't know the [website](https://forthodoxy.wordpress.com) at all, but it does seem to address your question.)

Answer (score -3):

The Sephardim who performed chalita don't do it anymore based on scientific basis. The machloket for hundreds of years was wether chalita was a requirement for kashering meat or it did the opposite and rendered it non-kosher. Science shows that chalita makes it impossible to ever kasher the meat. So to answer your question, nobody nowadays practices chalita

Comment: Your conclusion is simply false, as many Teimanim still do it.